# Creating an indoor map

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, maps, yahoo-api

I wonder if someone here can help here ,in my web application I'm trying to create map section:
In my map section the objective is to show an indoor search like in the attached picture from Yahoo Maps does someone know how they Created the tenants names and level of the floor on the maps it self?

http://s30.postimg.org/4dh7mlpfl/Yahoo_Maps.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best answer for this one is going to depend on which mapping framework you were interested in using.

If you're using Yahoo maps: Yahoo got that indoor map data from Nokia's [here](http://here.com/) platform.  As far as I know, they don't offer an editor for the indoor mapping data.  The major mapping platforms often have some self-service mechanism to add or correct mapping data.  If you were set on having this available and you were using Yahoo's maps, you might want to try to contact someone at Nokia's "here" and see how you might be able to get that to happen.

With that being said, you can do something like that with Google Maps as well.  They have information and a way to add the interior layout of a building [here](https://www.google.com/maps/about/partners/indoormaps/).  I haven't used it...I just know that it exists, so I can't speak to it in much detail.

There is also some support for this kind of thing in OpenStreetMap.  I would post a link to an example of it, but stackoverflow says I can't post more than 2 links unless I have more than 10 reputation.  (Sorry...I'm still relatively new to posting on here.)